# loading gif image display another frame. use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

[image]

please look at the above html frame.

if i click menu on [Menu] frame,

then loading gif image will display [Load page] frame.

but gif image display only [Menu] frame......

```js
$("#mmeload").click(function() {
  $('#loader').show();
  $setTimeout(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
  }, 6500);
});
```

```css
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)url('/images/default.gif') no-repeat 50%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dTree">
    <div class="loader" id="loader" style="display:none"></div>
    <a href="setup/mmeContextView.php" id="mmeload" target="view">MME Info</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

if click menu, then show gif image, and hide after 6500 micro sec..

how can i displaying anohter page...?

i already use post, load function...

Comment: Is your 'frame' mean html <iframe> tag? in your html code i didn't find iframe.

Comment: and i think your css have to contains 'z-index' property.

Comment: Remove `$` from `$setTimeout`, `setTimeout()` doesn't need `$`.

Comment: LIXer , not iframe. frame file is separation to other file....

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code and I guess your issue will be cleared.

```js
$("#mmeload").click(function() {
  $('#loader').show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
  }, 6500);
});
```

```css
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)url('/images/default.gif') no-repeat 50%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dTree">
    <div class="loader" id="loader" style="display:none"></div>
    <a href="setup/mmeContextView.php" id="mmeload" target="view">MME Info</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```